# No "connect wireless Network" option 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

So I have recently reinstalled Ubuntu (16.04.1 LTS) after a while of not using it. I have come across an issue with Wifi connections.
I can connect to a Wired network but am unable to connect to wifi and have no option for "connect wireless Network" in the network tab :(
I have had a brows through the forums and this seems to be a common issue, unfortunately none of the work-arounds seem to help. I think its probably a driver issue, so if anyone knows of a driver for my hardware then that would be sweet, other wise any solution would obviously be helpful :).

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
```

rfkill list all:

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Not sure if all thats overly helpful, so let me know if there is something else I can help with..

EDIT!!!

I found an answer that seemed to help alot of other people:

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms build-essential
git clone https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E.git
cd MT7630E/
sudo make dkms
```

I ran this and it told me that the driver was successfully installed! I thought YAY!! 
but still no Wireless Network option and when I unplug the Ethernet cable, it doesn't auto search for Wifi :(

Hope the extra info helps me find an answer..

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: You will see what happens if you run `sudo modprobe mt7630e`.

Comment: OMG!!! I freaking love you hahahhaha.. I disabled secure boot in the Bios and when the laptop came back on I had the Wifi Options in the networking tab! it is now working just fine! thankyou so so much!!!!

Comment: @Pilot6 could this effect my ability to use Wifi on the Windows 10 partition?

Comment: It is not related to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling "secure boot" in the bios worked for me! after months I have such an easy answer!

step1:
restart computer and enter Bios by pressing F2 or F11 or what ever it is for your computer manufacturer.

step2:
go to Boot security, and select safe boot.
disable it!

step3:
continue with start up and enjoy Wifi!!